# How to resolve Connection Timed Out Exception in java Sockets?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, exception, connection-timeout

I've been working on a Swing application and when i wanted to add an option, where the user can send files via the  local network, i had faced some serious problems.

To send the files through the network, i used the Sockets library to create a connection between the client and the server, the Source Code of **Client.java** is :

```
        package Test;

        import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.net.Socket;


        public class Client{
        public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
         int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

         long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
         int bytesRead;
         int current = 0;

          Socket sock = null;
          try{
          sock = new Socket("192.168.1.107",1234);
         }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           e.getCause();
          }
           System.out.println("Connecting...");

           // receive file
          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
          InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\test-copy.txt");
          BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
          bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
          current = bytesRead;


           do {
             bytesRead =
             is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
            if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end-start);
            bos.close();
            sock.close();
            sock.getPort();
    }
   }
```

and the Source Code of  **Server.java** is :

```
   package Test;

   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.net.ServerSocket;
   import java.net.Socket;


   public class Server{
   public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
   // create socket
   ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1234);
   while (true) {
  System.out.println("Waiting...");

  Socket sock = servsock.accept();
  //servsock.set
  System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

  // sendfile
  File myFile = new File ("C:\\testing\\test.txt");
  byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
  System.out.println("Sending...");
  os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  os.flush();
  sock.close();
  }
}
}
```

As you can see, i want to send a **test.txt** file from my computer to another computer that exists in the local network.
when i run the **Server.Java** and the **Client.java** i get an exception in the terminal mentioning that the **Connection is timed out** :

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    Connecting...
at  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at Test.NewClass1.main(Client.java:27)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test.Client.main(Client.java:36)
```

And what confused me more is that when i run the application using my **Localhost** , the copy of the file **test-copy.txt** is well created, i have looked for the reasons of the exception, i found that  it might be the **Firewall** privileges, and i enabled transactions for  the **port : 1234** but i still got the same error.

What i am asking for here is, is it a matter of authorities or privileges?  my computer is set as an administrator and the destination too, or what am i suppose to add or to modify to make it work properly?

I hope that i made my question clear.

Thank you :).

Comment: You should try asking for a port on each run. They must ofcourse match at both server and client. The reason being, reusing ports at times throws this error. I know generally it says address in use, but if you have'nt closed your connections properly for instance, this message is seen

Comment: I used the port 1234 for the first time and i get the same error,
one more question please : can i access the C:/ partition in the server hard disk , because the destination in my case is the server itself :D ?

Comment: Basic network debugging at play here. Can you look up the IP address of the machine by hostname, if you connect by hostname? If no, your program can't either. Can you telnet the machine on IP and port? If no, your program can't reach it either. Usually this is a firewall that blocks traffic, possibly on both sides.

Comment: I'm assuming the client asks for a file and it's relative to the server's installation dir. So files from c:, I'm sure - it depends I guess.

Comment: Can u tell us which statement throws the null pointer? That must help. Line 27 I guess

Comment: Does `C:\Test`-Dir exist on Client?

Comment: The statement that throws the NullPointerException is :
   InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

Comment: C:\Test exists in the client side of course :)

Comment: I cannot see why sock.getIntputStream() should throw a NPE without an exception before "Connecting..." then. Is this the case? No exception before that? The stacktrace has a connection timeout ... can you check explicitly sock for not being null, before calling getInputSTream, please?

Comment: No, here is the exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Test.Client.main(Client.java:36)

Comment: @ZakariaMarrah : Please do specify your Operating System also. Since under Windows 7, sometimes you have to go to the Advance Settings of your Windows Firewall under Control Panel, and provide Inbound and Outbound Rules. Sometimes things work that way, when you provide those rules.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish Reusing ports does not throw this error. Where do you get that from?.

Comment: My Operating System is Windows 7.

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali : i did what you said, i enabled the Inbound and Outbound rules but it stills the same.

Comment: @ZakariaMarrah : Now if you are using a Router in between, try to forward your ports for the respective IP also. This has to work, since I guess I did something like this to solve the same issue some time back (Though I forgot the details as to whether I did this thingy only to sort thingies out or something more). Upvoted this a long time back, else could've done that for more attention.

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali would you tell me how to forward the ports.
ANother thing is that i had modified the Host file in C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\  by changing the IPadress, does it make any difference ?

Comment: Depending on the Router used by you, everyone has different steps, better you go through the manual of your Router. For something like Port Forwarding or Virtual Servers, you have to specify a port and the Local IP of the respective machine.